# Cross-talk in an RGB photodiode circuit

Tags: voltage-measurement, photodiode, detection

I'm trying to make an accurate RGB detector, where the R,G, and B components of a sample are measured via the voltages
$$V_R, V_G, ~\text{and}~V_B,~\text{defined in the following circuit:}$$

[image: The Circuit]

Where the voltmeters are the ADC on the Arduino Due, and where the splitting into three channels goes on in a single component: The [Hamamatsu S9702](http://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s9702_kspd1071e.pdf):
[image: The RGB diode]

The problem is, when I vary the resistance in one channel (from 10 megohms to something else), the readings in the other channels are vastly affected. For example, here is some data from a blue LED source:
[image: Source = Blue LED, Evidence of Cross-channel effects:]

- Since there is cross-talk (i.e. the voltage in any given channel is dependent on the conditions in the other channels), does this mean I should scrap this design?
- Or is this design still okay, provided that the resistances in each channel are precisely the same?
- Is there a version of this circuit where the channels are truly independent (keep in mind that the RGB diode has 4 pins, and thus only takes in one voltage source)?

Comment: Please link to the specific parts you are using.

Comment: Just added the diode.

Comment: Is it possible the ambient light changed while you were changing resistors? Or temperature?

Comment: That's a really interesting suggestion. I don't recall this - the lights were always off, and the components were in a covered black box. However, I should try this again. I'll get back to you tomorrow

Comment: nope, still have interdependence of channels. change of resistance in one affects the voltage in the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the ADC: **Because the voltage signal has a very high output impedance, currents are leaking through the analog inputs, causing channel crosstalk.**

The photodiode circuit is, effectively, the following, where I claim that the Vout pin (which we treat as the output) has a very high impedance, thus causing problems:

[image]

Here is the rough calculation:
[image]

In our circuit, R = 10MΩ, which is much greater than the ADC input impedance. Finally, it suffices to demonstrate that high source impedance causes crosstalk within an ADC, and that is explained in **"Section 6: Symptoms of High Source Impedance"**, of the following document: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spna061/spna061.pdf.

Let me know if you have any questions or comments!

Answer (score 3):

You should not be seeing any cross-talk. Plus, your schematic is wrong. The sensor is a common-cathode unit, so the circuit should look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftbwL0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The fact that your voltages are acting funny suggests that you've done something very wrong. Your schematic also shows no connection to the other end of the power supply and I suspect that that is exactly what you've done. If this is true, your photodiodes are being operated in photovoltaic mode, and this would explain a lot. Please recheck both your power supply polarity and the connections.

If you have failed to make the power supply connection, your circuit looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA5XDu.png)</sup>

and changing one resistance will change all the measured voltages.

Comment: Thanks man! The common cathode is connected to the 5V pin on an Arduino Due, and the three voltage channels connect to three independent GND's on the Due. Is this correct?$$$$ I can't find an "other end" to the power supply pin, because it is connected straight into the board.

Comment: You seem to be doing things OK, then. But I have to ask - are you sure you're running your +5 to the right pin of the sensor? Look carefully for the index on the package.

Comment: Yes, I am very certain. I used a microscope to determine orientation, and then referred to the datasheet. Crap this is bad - I guess this is a very mysterious problem with no solution. Perhaps the soldered connection to the power supply isn't good. I'll keep on trying random things.$$$$ Is there anything you recommend?

Comment: Wait a minute - "three independent GND's"? You mean the two between Vin and +5, and the one just above PWM 13? If so, connect all three together and use a single tie point to the GND next to the +5. What I don't understand is that the blue voltage is behaving just as it ought to, but it's the other two that are flaky.

Comment: The problem with tying together each of the three together is that the circuits are then connected. At least with three separate GND's, they are at least in principle uncorrelated

Comment: yes, the other two are flaky - it's baffling to me that the R and G channels are affected. The same happens when I decrease the resistance on the R and G channels - the entire circuit responds...

Comment: With microamp currents, correlation is simply not something to be concerned with. If, somehow, you got 1 ohm of common resistance in the grounds, this would produce 1 microvolt of error.

Answer (score 2):

[Photodiodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode) are *current-generating* devices, not voltage-generating. They also are designed to work in reverse-bias, which seems correct if the schematic is drawn correctly (-5v supply.)

Since the [datasheet](http://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s9702_kspd1071e.pdf) was not specified, I had to go hunting. This particular device only generates 1uA for 10,000 lux. In other words, it doesn't output much current. Which isn't surprising, considering it's size. What isn't specified in the datasheet is reverse leakage current; generally this is small, such as 1nA. However, the datasheet shows that the output is 1nA for 10 lux. In other words, the leakage current is pretty close to the generated (photo) current. So changing one of the other bias resistors, can negatively affect the blue channel due to the leakage current being so close to the active current.

Generally, [op-amps](http://electronicdesign.com/analog/improved-photodiode-pre-amp-uses-current-feedback-amplifier) are used to amplify and scale the tiny currents generated into something more usable. This image is taken from the linked article. It would be possible to implement the existing RGB sensor using three op-amps, and get three signals out, amplified and scaled to the exact range you desire, with much less "cross-talk" as no equi-connected biasing is going on (each op-amp input is independent.)

[image: Op-amp current-to-voltage converter by Bob Briano]

This is pretty old op-amp (and possibly unnecessarily high-speed); if you don't need that kind of speed, less expensive ones will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, rdtsc! However, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_current_(physics), reverse bias leakage current is called "Dark current", which is actually listed on the data sheet.

Comment: With 5 volts of reverse bias, the dark current in our case is $$5pA$$, which is 200x smaller than your estimate. So with the bright LED (~10,000 lux) and the photocurrent being about $$1\mu A,$$ we get the ratio

$$\frac{\text{Photocurrent}}{\text{Dark Current}} = 200,000.$$

Comment: However, I am very interested in this cross-talk mechanism you describe: "So changing one of the other bias resistors, can negatively affect the blue channel due to the leakage current being so close to the active current." Could you clarify this statement? 
$$$$
As we can see from the plot, all channels, not just the blue channel, experience a reduction in signal by the change in resistance. In fact, if only the blue channel were affected, that would mean that the effects were confined to the blue channel, and thus no cross-talk (which would have been good)

Comment: Also, this is a great point: "Photodiodes are current-generating devices, not voltage-generating." The logic is that we can convert the photocurrent to a "photovoltage" via Ohm's law, by multiplying by a resistance (which handily serves as an amplifier):
$$\text{photovoltage} = R\cdot \text{photocurrent}$$
That's actually why the resistances are so high, so that the signal can be seen (R = 10 megohms). I now wonder, since you advise against measuring voltages, what are the disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the rigorous follow-up. Couple of questions: 1) Did you measure the reverse leakage at 5pA? That's spec'd at 1v. 2) You call it "cross-talk", I just used your words. In reality, those resistances are in parallel with the source resistance and currents of the diodes. So reducing any one of them affects the others perceived "sensitivity" i.e. "cross-talk." See the next image (right-click, open in new page.) If you have instruments to measure down to pA, I'll plug in real values. 3) 4) This is why op-amps are so popular. High input impedance, channel isolation, amp, scale, etc

Comment: ![Photodiode Current](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49416397/PhotodiodeCurrent.png)

Comment: "those resistances are in parallel with the source resistance and currents of the diodes." - thanks - 1) what is the source resistance (is it the resistance of the LED source)? 2) how are the circuits in parallel? Doesn't that seem like a fundamental design flaw of Hamamatsu's?

Comment: " 1) Did you measure the reverse leakage at 5pA? That's spec'd at 1v." wait what do you mean? 1v isn't a quantity of current, is it? I got 5pA from pp.2 of the data sheet: Dark current vs. reverse voltage

Comment: Also, could you send me the code you used for that plot? that could be incredibly useful :)

Comment: Source resistance is the internal resistance of the power source. The datasheet states that "reverse dark current" is 5pA, but in the fine print, was measured @ 1v bias. Your circuit is applying 5v, so the dark current will no longer be 5pA. I wish it could be measured, would be interesting to see what it really is. The common-cathode IC isn't a design flaw at all. As soon as a smaller value resistor is added, it drops the "sensitivity" because everything is wired in [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Resistors_2).

Comment: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49416397/PhotodiodeBiasing.asc) is the schematic, and here is [LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/). Have fun. :)

Comment: What's the solution then? can I wire everything in series?

Comment: You could either use op-amps to mitigate the bias resistance differences and provide scaling and amplification, or keep the bias resistances identical and wire it according to what Dave or @WhatRoughBeast suggest. The "common anode" forces all to be wired in parallel, however it wouldn't matter if they were individual elements, as connecting them separately would put them in parallel anyways.